# How to make `from . import utils` work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
some-tools-dir/
    base_utils.py
    other_utils.py
    some-tool.py
    some-other-tool.py

some-other-tools-dir/
    basetools -> symlink to ../some-tools-dir
    yet-another-tool.py
```

In `other_utils.py`, I have:

```
import base_utils
```

Now, in `yet-another-tool.py`, I want to do:

```
import basetools.other_utils
```

That doesn't work, because Python does not recognize `basetools` as a Python package.
So I add an empty `basetools/__init__.py`.
Now, in `other_utils`, I get the exception:

```
    import base_utils
ImportError: No module named base_utils
```

So I change that line to:

```
from . import base_utils
```

And `yet-another-tool.py` works now.

However, `some-tool.py` does not work anymore. It imports `other_utils`, and there I get the exception:

```
    from . import base_utils
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Now, I can add this hack/workaround to `some-tools-dir/*-tool.py`:

```
import os, sys
__package__ = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path += [os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))]
__import__(__package__)
```

And in addition, make all local imports relative in those files.

That solves the problem, I guess. However, it looks somewhat very ugly and I have to modify `sys.path`. I tried several variations of this hack, however, I want to support multiple Python versions if possible, so using the module `importlib` becomes complicated, esp. because I have Python 3.2, and I don't like using module `imp` because it's deprecated. Also, it only seems to become more complicated.

Is there something I'm missing? This all looks ugly and too complicated for a use-case which doesn't seem to be too uncommon (for me). Is there a cleaner/simpler version of my hack?

A restriction I'm willing to make is to only support Python >=3.2, if that simplifies anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Note that this answer was built by piecing together information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/2073595) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11536764/2073595), so go up-vote them if you like it)*

This looks a bit less hacky, and at least works with Python 2.7+:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    import sys, os.path as path
    sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))

from some_tools_dir import other_utils
```

I think the main reason you're finding this difficult is because it's actually unusual to have executable scripts inside of a python package. Guido van Rossum actualy calls it an ["antipattern"](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html). Normally your executable lives above the root directory of the package, and then can simply use:

```
from some_tools_dir import other_utils
```

Without any fuss.

Or, if you want to execute a script that lives in the package, you actually call it as part of the package (again, from the parent dir of the package):

```
python -m some_tools_dir.other_utils
```

Comment: Note that I used directory names with "-" by intention in my question, because I wanted to have a general solution. Your solution assumes that it is a valid package name (`some_tools_dir`). --- However, I decided to restructure my files and follow Guidos advice. Also, the `python -m` is not a real solution because I want to be able to have the scripts executable and I don't see how I can accomplish that via hashbang.

Answer (score 0):

Are you be able to add the top root path into PYTHONPATH ?

If so, you can then add

```
__init__.py
```

file into some-tools-dir (and/or some-other-tools-dir)

Then from other_utils.py you do

```
from some-tools-dir import base_utils
```

And in yet-another-tool.py you do

```
from some-tools-dir import other_utils
```

You can then remove the symlink, and have proper namespacing.

Comment: I already did that. That is what I wrote in my question. Also, your code does not work because module names can not contain `"-"`.