# ModuleNotFoundError when using symbolic links

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have the following directory structure

```sh
parent_directory/
+-- utils.py
+-- child_directory/
|   +-- script.py
+-- results_directory/
|   +-- results1
|   +-- results2
```

There are several scripts in `child_directory/` that do not import anything from each other. However all of them import stuff from `utils.py` in the `parent_directory/` and use data from `results_directory`. Instead of copying scripts to the parent directory one by one. I want to just make a soft symbolic link of the `child_directory/script.py` file in `parent_directory`. From within the `parent_directory` I make the link using `ln -s child_directory/script.py .` or `ln -s absolute/path/to/child_directory/script.py .`. And then use `python script.py` to run the script.

The following is an example code of `script.py`:

```py
from utils.py import results_reader

# Do work
```

When I run the script using the symbolic link in the `parent_directory` I get the following error:

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

I don't quite understand what's happening here. `os.getcwd()` shows the current path to be the `parent_directory/`. Shouldn't it be able to read the `utils.py` file? When I run `script.py` by copying it to `parent_directory/` it runs without errors

And when I change `from utils.py import results_reader` to `from .utils.py import results_reader`, I get the following error:

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.utils'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826005/how-to-make-from-import-utils-work

Comment: @AsifRaza thanks for the link to the answer but unfortunately that doesn't answer my question