# Importing Utils in Python

Tags: python

I have Python 3.9.7  and I have already installed utils==1.0.1.

So now I want to import this library and trying with this command

```
from . import utils
```

But this is not working. I receive this error :

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make \`from . import utils\` work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826005/how-to-make-from-import-utils-work)

Comment: Before sending my question I saw this answer but is not work for me.

Comment: So you already installed a package called utils? I assume then that it's in your lib, can you just do `import utils`?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is some confusion around `utils`. I think you installed a Python package via pip, i.e. `pip install python-utils`. If that is the case, then you need:

```
import python_utils
```

Also you should check out their [quickstart](https://python-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#quickstart) for that package.

There are many reasons not to use the `.` methodology, but the main one here is you're not actually accessing a parent folder, you're accessing a site package that you've installed. These will *always* be `import X`.

e.g.:

`pip install numpy`

```
import numpy
```

And if you're curious run `pip show <package>` to know where it is installed. It should be under `site-packages`.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to import from a folder that is not recognised as a python package (it must have an `_init_.py` file to be recognised as a package) can raise this error.

If `utils` is a package try importing it directly like
`from utils import *` or
`import utils`

Answer (score 1):

```
import utils
```

Dont use this:

```
from . import *anything*
```

In file hierarchy `.` means current directory and python tries to find `from {file}` this file in the same level, where you launched your code. You should also read info about `../` file hierarchy in unix systems to understand how python works with files.

Comment: Thanks! Is working and I can import it. But again something is missing. I received this error  'AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'extract_values' '

Comment: maybe you should use .values() Please give the context, where do you use value extraction